# Acumatica update field OpenOrderQty / Soshipline

Tags: acumatica

I would like to modify the ShippedQty field by putting the same value as the OpenOrderQty field after adding the line, but that does nothing. I removed the PXDefault. The value stay at 0.00.

```
protected void SOShipLine_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e, PXRowInserted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
  if(InvokeBaseHandler != null)
    InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
  var row = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
   if (row==null) {return;}
   row.ShippedQty=row.OpenOrderQty;
}
```

Thanks.
Xavier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest you to not set the *ShippedQty* because it might have some implications as it is a calculated field. Instead, you can create a *custom field* and set the value of *OpenOrderQty* to that field.

Answer (score 0):

When the RowInserted event is fired, the data has already been inserted into the cache so it's too late to try and edit the data.  You should change this to use a RowInserting() event.  See more details [here](https://help-2021r1.acumatica.com/(W(4))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=04839388-1c8f-4d49-888e-d3167ce3578d)